# Show that $\sqrt{9+a} \geq \sqrt{a} + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1 + a}}$

Tags: inequality, self-learning, recreational-mathematics

I encountered this recreational problem:

Show that $\sqrt{9+a} \geq \sqrt{a} + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1 + a}} \quad \forall a \geq 0$. I also have to assess in what cases the equality holds. I am new to problem solving and tried some algebraic manipulations but don't seem to get far.

Comment: One way is to try to manipulate the given inequality into something you know is true. I would try to multiply by $\sqrt{1+a}$, square the inequality, simplify (i.e. isolate remaining $\sqrt{\cdot}$) and square again. This should leave you with a inequality $p(a) \geq 0$ where $p(a)$ is a polynomial (quadratic I think it will be). To show that a polynomial is positive you can for example try to factor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all is positive and we can square the inequality
$$9+a>a+\frac{8}{1+a}+\frac{4\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}$$
it is equivalent to
$$\frac{1+9a}{1+a}>\frac{4\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}$$
this is equivalent to
$$(1+81a^2+18a)(1+a)>32a(1+a^2+2a)$$
in this is
$$(1+a)(7a-1)^2>0$$
is true.

Comment: you are welcome!